# About the function $x^2\sin{\frac 1 x}$ .

Tags: analysis

My problem is to disprove, using the function $g(x):=x^2\sin{\frac 1 x}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g(0):=0$, the following statement:

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable. Let $(t_n)$ be a sequence converging to some $c\in(a,b)$. Then $\lim_n f'(x_n)=f'(c)$.

By looking into the graph of $y=g'(x)$, I see that there exist a sequence $(s_n)$ converging to $0$, such that $\lim_n f'(s_n)=1\ne0=f'(0)$. But I don't know how to proof the existence of such sequence.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n\pi}$?

Comment: How is this function possibly differentiable at $x=0$? If you look at the [graph of the derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+x%5E2*sin%281%2Fx%29), the graph is going all over the place near $x=0$.

Comment: @ Noble, differrentiability does not imply continuous derivative.

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Then how is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ defined? Isn't this $\lim_{h \to 0} h\cdot sin(1/x)$? -- Oh, wait, [the limit of this is defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832068/about-the-function-x2-sin-frac-1-x#1832068). Sorry about that!

Comment: @NobleMushtak $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ h^2\sin \frac{1}{h}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} h\sin \frac{1}{h} =0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see $$f'(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 2x \sin\left( \tfrac 1 x \right) - \cos\left( \tfrac 1 x \right), & x \neq 0, \\ 0, & x = 0. \end{matrix} \right.$$ If we put $x_n = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$ then $$f(x_n) = \tfrac{2}{(2n+1)\pi} \sin((2n+1)\pi) - \cos((2n+1)\pi).$$ But $\sin((2n+1)\pi) = 0$ and $\cos((2n+1)\pi) = -1$ so $$f(x_n) = 1$$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. However, it is clear that $x_n \to 0$.

Comment: Here $f$ is continuous and differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$. So you could take the interval to be $\mathbb R$ or if you really wanted a finite interval just take it to be $(-a,a)$ for any $a > 0$ (then of course we will need to restrict to large enough $n$ so that $x_n \in (-a,a)$). EDIT: This comment was in response to other comments which have since been deleted.

Comment: My bad understanding!!! You are right! I did not notice to the function very well. Thanks.